# Problem using yfonts / gothic

Tags: fonts

I'm using TexLive 2014, last update yesterday

```
tlmgr info yfonts gothic
package:     yfonts
installed:   Yes
cat-date:    2012-04-16 12:07:42 +0200

package:     gothic
installed:   Yes
cat-date:    2014-05-03 14:16:52 +0200
```

When I process this file (pdflatex/xelatexy)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts,color}
\begin{document}
\yinipar{\color{red}L}orem ipsum \ldots
\end{document}
```

it produces following error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf yinitas
! I can't find file `yinitas'.
```

Has anybody succesfully used yfonts or gothic with a recent TL2014? I tried more examples from SE, but it seems that something changed since then.

Maybe I should rephrase the question: What steps do I have to take in order to use the beautiful gothic initials of Yannis Haralambous?

I do have:

```
find -iname '*yinit*'

./doc/fonts/gothic/yinit.pdf
./doc/fonts/gothic/README.yinit
./fonts/tfm/public/gothic/yinit.tfm
./fonts/source/public/gothic/yinitW.mf
./fonts/source/public/gothic/yinitZ.mf
./fonts/source/public/gothic/yinitT.mf
....
```

but reading README.yinit does not really help me.

Comment: It seems that `yinitas` and `yinitdd` have been dropped from the package. This is confirmed at http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/gothic/

Comment: `yinitas` has been split from `yinit`. See http://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/gothic/yinit-as. This is according to author. I imagine, though I'm not sure, that the files kept in TeX Live are the ones for which a clear licence is available. Look at`doc/fonts/gothic/README.yinit` in your `TEXMF`.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase the question: What steps do I have to take in order to use the beautiful gothic initials of Yannis Haralambous?

Comment: Get the files from CTAN (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/yinit-as or through the miktex package http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/yinit-as.tar.lzma), put them "where they can be found" and if necessary update your file name database with texhash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a hint of Ulrike Fischer on c.t.t I found the following solution:

Step 1: download (and unzip) [yinit-as.zip](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/gothic/yinit-as.zip) from CTAN. It contains:

```
yinit-as/
 yinit-as/initials.sty
 yinit-as/yinitas.txt
 yinit-as/README
 yinit-as/yinitas.tfm
 yinit-as/yinitas.mf
```

Step 2: put the files where tex can find them (e.g in ~/texmf or .../texmf-local)

```
md .../texmf-local/fonts/tfm/yinit-as
cp yinit-as/yinitas.tfm .../texmf-local/fonts/tfm/yinit-as
md .../texmf-local/fonts/source/yinit-as
cp yinit-as/yinitas.mf .../texmf-local/fonts/source/yinit-as
md .../texmf-local/doc/yinit-as
cp yinit-as/{README,yinitas.txt} .../texmf-local/doc/yinit-as
md .../texmf-local/tex/latex/yinit-as
cp yinit-as/initials.sty .../texmf-local/tex/latex/yinit-as
```

Don't forget to run

```
mktexlsr
```

to update your search database

Answer (score 3):

I adjusted @egreg answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354402/how-to-translate-yinitial-macro-from-tex-to-latex/354420?noredirect=0#answer-354413)  with package `lettrine` as convenient way to use the beautiful gothic initials of Yannis Haralambous.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{4}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{0.5em}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{yinit}{m}{n}}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{-0.65}
\begin{document}
\lettrine{\color{purple}L}{orem ipsum odio metus}. \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Initial Haralambous L with lettrine]

I posted [here](https://www.academia.edu/31549706/Letras_capitulares_g%C3%B3ticas_en_LaTeX) a description (in spanish) to use Yannis Haralambous' initials.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by replacing yinitas with yinit in file yfonts.dtx.

Comment: @Guido It *is* an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `yfonts.sty` the value of `\initdefault` is `yinitas`, which is not installed in TeX Live. But `yinit` is installed, so you should redefine `\initdefault`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\def\initdefault{yinit}
\begin{document}
{\frakfamily\fraklines\yinipar{U}nd da er ihn fand, sprach er zu ihm:
Glaubest du an den Sohn Gottes? 36. Er antwortete und sprach:
Herr, welcher ist's ... Du hast ihn gesehen, und der mit dir
redet, der ist's. 38. Er aber sprach: Herr, ich glaube; und
betete ihn an. Und Jesus sprach: Ich bin zum Gerichte auf diese
Welt kommen, auf da\ss, die da nicht sehen, sehend werden, und
die da sehen, blind werden. Und solches höreten etliche der Pharis\"{a}er,
die bei ihm waren, und sprachen zu ihm: Sind wir denn auch blind?\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]