# How to translate yinitial macro from TeX to LaTeX?

Tags: drop-cap

There is this macro in TeX.

In Yannis Haralambous' TUG Conference presentation in 1990, https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb12-1/tb31hara.pdf, in Initials, in page 132, he wrote:

To typeset the initial D of Appendix B, I used the macro `\yinitial{D}` as follows (with `zero_depth:=false`)

```
\def\yinitial#1 
{\hangindent=2.54cm 
\hangafter=-4 
\hskip-3.24cm 
\lower-2.7mm 
\hbox{\yinit #1} 
\hskip1.5mm}
```

How to translate this macro in a `newcommand` in LaTeX to write the beautiful initial D exactly as in Appendix B?

Of course, I already have font `yinitas` installed properly.

[image: An amazing initial D!]

Comment: Use the `lettrine` package. I would test if you'd provided an MWE.

Comment: There are packages already set up but they are not strictly needed, the code as posted should work (there is a typo in the last line `1.5mrn` should be `1.5mm`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use lettrine but to answer the question as asked, the code should work more or less as is in latex, I made a couple of spacing adjustments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\font\yinit=yinit at 15pt

\def\yinitial#1{%
\hangindent=2.54cm 
\hangafter=-5 
\hskip-3.24cm 
\smash{\lower1.7cm \hbox{\yinit #1}}%
\hskip1.5mm
}

\begin{document}

\yinitial{D}\textsc{avid uses Yannis' code}. \kant[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer @David Carlisle, the second letter should be out of the initial square and should be small, not necessarily capital. I try to mimic the initial in the image.

Comment: @tatojo just remove the `\textsc` and  adjust the final `\hskip` to control where the normal text starts....

Comment: Right @DavidCarlisle, now it is matter to adjust space.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to point there is now an `opentype` version of this font, making it easier to scale and zoom in the viewer. The following example uses `fontspec` and can be compiled with `xelatex`  or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[marginratio={4:6, 5:7}, textwidth=131mm, noheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}% font selecting commands%
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}, Ligatures = Rare, WordSpace = 1.1}%,2
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}%
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant = british]{english}%
\newfontface{\yinit}{Yinit}
\usepackage{parskip, nicefrac}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\title{\color{Tomato2}\huge\bfseries\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=1} TO MAKE AN AMBLONGUS PIE}
\author{\Large Edward Lear}
\date{}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.1}
\setlength\DefaultFindent{0.1em}
\setlength\DefaultNindent{0.25em}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{Tan1}\yinit}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lettrine{T}{ake} 4 pounds (say 4 \nicefrac{1}{2} pounds) of fresh Amblongusses, and put them in a small pipkin.

\lettrine{C}{over} them with water and boil them for 8 hours incessantly, after which add 2 pints of new milk, and proceed to boil for 4 hours more.

\lettrine{W}{hen} you have ascertained that the Amblongusses are quite soft, take them out and place them in a wide pan, taking care to shake them well previously.

\lettrine{G}{rate} some nutmeg over the surface, and cover them carefully with powdered gingerbread, curry-powder, and a sufficient quantity of Cayenne pepper.

\lettrine{R}{emove} the pan into the next room, and place it on the floor. Bring it back again, and let it simmer for three-quarters of an hour. Shake the pan violently till all the Amblongusses have become a pale purple colour.

\lettrine{T}{hen}, having prepared a paste, insert the whole carefully, adding at the same time a small pigeon, 2 slices of beef, 4 cauliflowers, and any number of oysters.

\lettrine{W}{atch} patiently till the crust begins to rise, and add a pinch of salt from time to time.

\lettrine{S}{erve up} in a clean dish, and throw the whole out of the window as fast as possible.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks nice, will try it!

Comment: @tatojo: The recipe?

Comment: Of course! Well, the font too!

Answer (score 2):

Use `lettrine` and adjust the parameters, taking into account that `yinit` is a big font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{yinit}{m}{n}}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{4}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{-0.75}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{I}{t was} a dark and stormy night. \kant[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes @egreg, actualy I got this output with \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\yinipar{L}orem ipsum \lipsum[2]
\end{document}

Comment: @tatojo `lettrine` is much more customizable.

Comment: Right @egreg, its look like, I'll try that package. I supose you have `yinitas` font installed, isn' t?

Comment: @tatojo Yes, of course.

Comment: after checking the behavior of David adjusted TeX macro I asked for, I took a closer look to your answer about lettrine and your code. I could get the behavior I was looking for: \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lettrine,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{4}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{yinit}{m}{n}}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{-0.65}%{-0.75}
\begin{document}
\lettrine{\textcolor{purple}{L}}{\ orem ipsum odio metus}. \lipsum[2]
\end{document}