# yfonts is not working in the full TeXLive 2018 installation

Tags: drop-cap, yfonts

I have scanned the search results for the error message I am getting, and every answer had to do with the partial installation of TexLive, so installing collection-fontsrecommended or doing a full installation fixed the error in their cases. In my case I already have the full installation, and still getting the error:

> Font U/yinitas/m/n/9=yinitas not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
> found. \textbf{{\small\initfamily D}}}{rop cap}
>
> Font \U/yinitas/m/n/10=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
> found. \textbf{{\small\initfamily D}}}{rop cap}

when compiling this MWE with PdfLatex:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[lines=3]{\color{currentfancycolout} 
\textbf{{\small\initfamily D}}}{rop cap} of \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

If replacing `\initfamily` with `\yinipar` the error is:

> Font U/yinitas/m/n/35.45491=yinitas at 96.2pt not loadable: Metric
> (TFM) file not found. \lettrine[]{\textbf\yinipar{W}}{}
>
> Font \U/yinitas/m/n/24.88=nullfont not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
> found. \lettrine[]{\textbf\yinipar{W}}{}

I tried updating moments ago and got the same error.

What am I still missing?

Comment: The fonts are not in texlive. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229590/2388

Comment: Out of curiosity: why not?

Comment: Unclear license and so not suitable for texlive.

Comment: Got it, Ulrike, appreciate your help, as ever!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments